# How to set a default desktop environment at system start?

Tags: linux, kde, desktop-environments, kdm

I'm a Linux and KDE user, and recently I started to use also Enlightenment as a substitute Desktop environment when I need a lighter resource consumption.

I use KDM as a display manager, and I need to find a way to correctly set the default desktop environment to my preferences.

I wish to be able to set KDE as the default choice because I use it on a daily basis, and manually pick a different one just when I need it.

Currently it is set to boot the last used DE, and I can't find how to change this behaviour. 
The KDM control module in KDE System Settings does not seem to offer me this option.

Any clues on how can I do it?

Comment: Can't you chose a DE before logging in? There should be a `session` menu or similar that allows you to chose the session you want to run.

Comment: Yes, but I've set it up to automatically login with my account, without asking for a specific user (I'm the only user of the computer).

Comment: I don't think there is a way to both log in automatically and be able to chose a session.

Comment: I understand. But if it automatically logins in the last used environment, there should be some place where the system is told to behave like this, where it must check what was the last used and then to select it.

Comment: And, in your experience, is this behaviour specifically related to my display manager (KDM) or it's a setting that has nothing to do with it? Should I expect to have the same situation also with, in example, LightDM?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should be able to set this up by editing your `$HOME/.dmrc` file. The sessions available to your display manager (whichever one you use) are .desktop files normally located in `/usr/share/xsessions`. In my case, this directory contains:

```
$ ls /usr/share/xsessions
cinnamon2d.desktop  gnome-fallback.desktop  openbox-gnome.desktop  xfce.desktop
cinnamon.desktop    mate.desktop            openbox-kde.desktop
gnome.desktop       openbox.desktop         ssh.desktop
```

Any of those files is a possible session that my display manager can choose. Which one is controlled by the `$HOME/.dmrc` file. So, to make `KDE` the default, you would have to edit that file and make it look like this:

```
[Desktop]
Session=kde-plasma
```

That assumes that you have a `kde.desktop` file in the `xsessions` directory, I don't use KDE so I can't check but it works for me using `cinnamon` or `xfce`. Once you have made that change, you should be logged in to KDE by default every time.

Comment: Thank you. You like many different environments yourself, don't you? :)    Anyway, in my system, in the `/usr/share/xsessions`, the KDE entry is named `kde-plasma.desktop`; I suppose that this is because KDE also provides other environments (i.e. the Active for mobile devices) besides Plasma, the standard for desktops. Since I haven't modified anything here, I'm quite sure that it's the standard name; you might want to upgrade your answer to reflect this. I will try out this procedure and see if it works.

Comment: @Sekhemty thanks, answer edited. It should work, I installed kdm just for you :) and tested by switching between cinnamon and xfce, it logged me into the default each time.

Comment: Already done, at least for me it is shown as accepted. Maybe the server has not yet updated the status?

Comment: @Sekhemty damn, sorry, just noticed your rep level and realized you already know how the site works :). Yup, all accepted here too, thanks!

Comment: There is no problem!

Comment: does not work for me.I'm using CentOS 7. having gnome-classic.desktop, gnome.desktop, mate.desktop. set Session=mate but does not work

Comment: @vee maybe things have changed since then, it's been 2 years after all. Try asking a new question and linking to this answer, explaining that it didn't work. Make sure you tell us exactly what files you edited and also what login manager you are using.

Comment: It showed me lightdm-session. I replaced with gnome but not working.

Comment: @Pandya yes, see [the answer](https://superuser.com/a/1361577/151431) by yrHeTaTeJlb, it looks like it works differently these days.

Answer (score 13):

In GNOME 2, the `.dmrc` file in the user home directory was used to create default sessions. This `.dmrc` file is no longer used.

To specify a default session for a user, update the user’s account service in the `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/*username*` file:

```
[User]
Language=
XSession=mate
```

[Source](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/session-user.html.en)

Comment: My `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/*username*` contains "Session=" and "XSession=" variables. Should I set them both?

Comment: This did not work for me on Centos 7.9 :(

Comment: So I went `nano /var/lib/AccountsService/users/root` and put `Session=plasma` meaning the account service or whatever points to `/usr/share/xsessions/plasma.desktop` yeah? my filenames are a little different.

Answer (score 4):

Works for Centos 7/RHEL
If **$HOME/.dmrc** doesn't exists:

1. From dir **/usr/share/xsessions** move all *.desktop file to another directory(unnecessary_env, for example) and leave only one you need(in my case - xfce.desktop):

   `$ ls /usr/share/xsessions
   xfce.desktop  unnecessary_env/`
2. After logout/reboot XFCE will be loaded by default

Note! You won't be able to choose between GUI

Comment: My default desktop environment is not under /usr/share/xsessions. I'm on kali Linux and see System X11 Default and gnome-classic as options. But in xsessions, only gnome-classic.desktop exists. Any tips..?

Comment: Whatever I tried, Kali would keep using GNOME as default, moving the unnecessary *.desktop files out of /usr/share/xsessions was the only reliable method to force Kali to use Cinnamon by default. Thanks!

Comment: Same for me, it was the unique way to switch from budgie to cinnamon as default desktop in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Answer (score 4):

For RHEL/CentOS 7 you can set the file `/etc/sysconfig/desktop` to contain `DESKTOP=KDE` which will default it to KDE.

This also works for VNC.

Answer (score 1):

I tried many options. The worker turned out to be the following:

**MATE**

echo "exec /usr/bin/mate-session" >> ~/.xinitrc

**Cinnamon**

echo "exec /usr/bin/cinnamon-session" >> ~/.xinitrc

**KDE**

echo "exec startkde" >> ~/.xinitrc

[Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181503/how-to-install-desktop-environments-on-centos-7)