# Linux. Default desktop enviroment for each user

Tags: linux, arch-linux, login-screen, desktop-environments

I have Arch linux installed on my PC. 
There are two users and I want to configure LightDM than when first user login Awesome WM starts and when the second user login LXQt starts. 
I don't want that each user had to change DE manualy. Is it possible?

Login means ordinary login via LightDM-GTK-Greeter.

Comment: I know that there is ~/.dmrc file wich has last session type. Maybe greeter can use that file?

Comment: Looked at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/685970/how-to-set-a-default-desktop-environment-at-system-start)?

Comment: @xenoid, thanks, I have tried to change ~/.dmrc file, but it doesn'r work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=202266).

So for my case, I created a new xsession file:

*/usr/share/xsessions/smart_de.desktop*

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/share/startDE.sh 
Name=Smart DE change
Comment=Awesome for user1 and LXQt for others
```

and a script that launches a special DE for each user:

*/usr/share/startDE.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$USER" = "user1" ]; then
        exec awesome
else
        exec startlxqt
fi
```