# systemd: run a custom script before AccountsService loads

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome, systemd

I started a little project. I want to have a different default desktop environment selected in GDM (log-in screen) depending on whether I am running it on a hypervisor or simply baremetal. I have already created a script that has the basic logic to detect how it's being run, then changes the default entry appropriately. What I am concerned with is automatically running this script on startup, which swaps the value of `XSession` in `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/jeremy` to either `gnome` or `gnome-classic` (refer to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/685970/how-to-set-a-default-desktop-environment-at-system-start/1361577#1361577) for more info). I have several questions regarding this:

- How should I properly create the `.service` file to make sure my script (located at `/opt/DetectENV/switcher.sh`) gets executed before the `AccountsService` loads during startup? (I am using Fedora 30 Workstation if that helps)
- Where is the best place to put this `.service` file? Not sure if it should be `/etc/systemd/system/` or `/etc/systemd/user`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the option `Before=accounts-daemon.service` in [Unit]. This will work the same way as if accounts-daemon had an After= for *your* service: *if* both units are queued, then its startup will be delayed until your service completes initialization.

(This also means your service must use the correct type, i.e. usually `Type=oneshot`, to let systemd know when its initialization has in fact completed. In this case, because you want to run a simple command and wait until that command has *exited,* Type=oneshot is the correct choice.)

Note that your service must already be configured to start on boot in the normal way (that is, via WantedBy= and `systemctl enable`). The Before/After= options don't declare dependencies; they don't do anything more than inform systemd of the correct order.

All privileged services are system services. The only time you would create a 'user' service is when you want it to be started *after you log in* and bound to your user account. (For example, Dropbox or gnome-settings-daemon can be 'user' services.)

(Additionally, because 'system' and 'user' services are managed by entirely separate instances of *systemd*, ordering and dependencies only work between units within the same instance. That is, system units can only refer to other 'system' units; user units can only depend on other 'user' units.)